# need to run client/server in corba without using name service or file

Tags: corba

I need to run a client server application in corba using c++ without using name service or without managing a shared file.
Basically want to run the server on one port and client should connect to this.
But the port will be read in client side and this needs to be communicated to server.
Is there a way to achieve this communicating the port from client to server.

Comment: You need a different communication channel for doing this, can't the server read in the port number also?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I need the server to read the port that is passed by user as input parameter in client.

Comment: But how can the server know the port number when it is not started yet? Then you can't transfer to it. Normally the server is started on a fixed port number, the client constructs a IOR in code (he has to know the server and port number to connect to) and connects to the server